# How to connect to MongoDB 3.2 in Java with username and password?

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

I'm using MongoDB 3.2 in my application. The code below demonstrates database initialization logic:

```java
private void dbInit(String dbName) {

    String mongoClientURI = "mongodb://" + DB_URL + ":" + DB_PORT;
    MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI(mongoClientURI);

    // enable SSL connection
    MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(true).build();

    if (this.mongoClient == null) {
        this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    }

    // create database if doesn't exist
    this.mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);
}
```

This code works fine, now I want to introduce access level separation to database.

The steps to do that:

1. Define users:

```java
use myAppDB
db.createUser(
   {
      "user": "myAdmin",
      "pwd": "123090d1487dd4ab7",
      roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
   }
)

use myAppDB
db.createUser(
   {
      "user": "guest",
      "pwd": "guest",
      roles: [ "read" ]
   }
)
```

2. Re-create the MongoDB 3.2 service in authentication mode:
   `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe" --install --dbpath=C:\data\db --logpath=C:\data\log\log.txt --auth --service`. And run it.
3. Change the `mongoClientURI` connection string to

```java
String mongoClientURI = "mongodb://" + DB_SRV_USR + ":" + DB_SRV_PWD + "@" + DB_URL + ":" + DB_PORT;
```

where `DB_SRV_USR` = `myAdmin` and `DB_SRV_PWD` = `123090d1487dd4ab7`.

4. Check the authenticated connection in IDEA's `Mongo Explorer` with the same credentials, everything is OK.
5. Execute my application and get exception `Authentication failed`.

My questions:

1. How to connect to MongoDB 3.2 in Java with username and password? I saw a couple of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34085215/462347) but they are using deprecated methods.
2. Should I add my users to `myAppDB` or to `admin` table? In some tutorials I saw that users are created in `admin` table is it a good idea or it worth to create users only in a database they are going to work with?

Comment: Do you have an SSL-enabled `mongod`?

Comment: And make sure that you have `myAppDB` appended to your connection string and/or use the [authSource parameter](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#uri.authSource).

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, I enabled SSL in the settings of Mongo Explorer plugin.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, btw, in some tutorials I saw that users are created in `admin` table is it a good idea or it worth to create users only in a database they are going to work with?

Comment: ***My*** rule of thumb: if the user only has roles on one DB, create the user there. If the user has roles in multiple DBs, create the user in the "primary" DB (usually the first one he or she connects to). For everything else, I use "admin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MarkusWMahlberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296707/markus-w-mahlberg) correctly noted, it is necessary to note the database name in the connection string.

For instance:

```
String mongoClientURI = "mongodb://" + DB_SRV_USR + ":" + DB_SRV_PWD + "@" + DB_URL + ":" + DB_PORT + "/" + dbName;
```

Answer (score 18):

Tested with mongodb-3.4.2 and mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar

(1) Use MongoCredential

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("user", "database", "passwd".toCharArray());
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), Arrays.asList(credential));
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase( "test" );
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("mycol");
FindIterable fi = collection.find();
MongoCursor cursor = fi.iterator();
```

(2) Use MongoClientURI

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user:passwd@localhost:27017/?authSource=test");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

There are some variant forms for using MongoCredential and MongoClientURI for different authentication mechanisms, check [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/) for details