# com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using remote MongoDB and connecting that with my Spring boot application. Application works fine if I define *spring.data.mongodb.uri* in my **application.properties** file, along with username and password.
Something similar to

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

I wanted to keep encoded url in my application.property file and then want to decode it before use. 
I am using MongoOperations to query mongoDB.

I tried to create MongoDBTemplate in **Configuration** class, but it is throwing

> com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of
>   stream

Here's the code

```
package com.expensemanagement.base;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

        char[] password2 = "XXXX".toCharArray();
        MongoCredential credential2 = MongoCredential.createCredential("XXXX", "MongoDB",password2);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("XXX-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.mongodb.net",27017), Arrays.asList(credential2));
        MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, "MongoDB");
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);

    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079876/mongosocketreadexception-prematurely-reached-end-of-stream-after-a-period-of-i

Comment: I answered to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289948/mongosocketreadexception-prematurely-reached-end-of-stream-while-connecting-mo/76868718#76868718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer at [How to connect to MongoDB 3.2 in Java with username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392797/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-3-2-in-java-with-username-and-password)

I have added custom property in application.property file and then in AppConfig class created MongoClient object as below.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${mongo.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${application.key}")
    private String secretKey;

    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient()
    {


        String decrptedUrl = DecryptionService.decrypt(url, secretKey);


        MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI(decrptedUrl);
        if (this.mongoClient == null) {
            this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        }

        return mongoClient;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### This worked for me in spring boot with cloud based mongo (clustered instances).

Edit application.properties like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb+srv://username:password@solarsystem-1tpu0.mongodb.net/dbname
```

For **regular mongo instances** (non-clustered) use this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://username:password@solarsystem-shard-00-00-1tpu0.mongodb.net:27017,hostname2:27017/dbname?ssl=true
```

- If you want to set other **connection options**, you can chain
  multiple parameters using '&' ; documentation here:
  https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html
- If you were using other **spring.data.mongodb parameters**, you should
  **remove all of them** otherwise spring won't read
  spring.data.mongodb.uri