# How to add auth to mongoDB and connect it to spring boot app

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I have following spring boot config:

```
spring.data:
  mongodb:
    database: customer
    host: localhost
    port: 27017
    uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb
```

Docker compose :

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://db/spring-demo
  db:
    image: mongo:3.6.2
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

And my dockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD /build/libs/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

I need to add authorization to my database (login, password). 
What do I need to change in docker config and spring boot config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create user in mongodb with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423659/how-to-create-user-in-mongodb-with-docker-compose)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to MongoDB 3.2 in Java with username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392797/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-3-2-in-java-with-username-and-password)